# I have a problem following Youtube tutorial and put the sam code and still not working... error is Compiled with problems:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, native

This is an error in React Native

> Compiled with problems:
>
> ERROR in ./src/App.js 5:0-42
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/Dashboard' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\ReactNative\dev\mern-tutorial\frontend\src'
>
> ERROR in ./src/App.js 6:0-34
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/Login' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\ReactNative\dev\mern-tutorial\frontend\src'
>
> ERROR in ./src/App.js 7:0-40
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/Register' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Desktop\ReactNative\dev\mern-tutorial\frontend\src'

And this is code:

App.js is:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Register from './pages/Register'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <div className='container'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.jsx is:

```
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>Dashboard</div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Login.jsx is:

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div>Login</div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

and Register.jsx is:

```
function Register() {
  return (
    <div>Register</div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

I installed `npm i react-dom` I found that on internet forums that I need but it doesn't help.
While starting I use command `npm start --prefix frontend`.
I installed `npm i react-router-dom`.
I approach my frontend with `cd frontend`.
I use commands like `npm run client`, but it only works when I `run npm start --prefix frontend` then frontend starts but I got that problem with routes.

I have Register.jsx Login.jsx and Dashboard.jsx as simple as possible with just one div so there could not be an error in it.

Comment: Hello! Generally we prefer if solutions/clarifying questions are done here on Stack Overflow not in an email, so future people can benefit from the solution, so your contact information may be edited out as a result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.